# difference on date condition in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, difference, window-functions

```
name  total     date 
a     100     1/2/2015 
b     30      1/2/2015 
c     40      1/2/2015 
d     45      1/2/2015 
a     20      2/2/2015
b     13      2/2/2015 
a     30      3/2/2015
b     23      3/2/2015
c     20      3/2/2015
```

and the table goes on with different dates,
I want to find difference(a-b) for each date and occurence ..  i.e

```
diff  total  date 
a-b    70    1/2/2015
a-b    7     2/2/2015....
```

how do I do it in postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nth_value()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) window function for that:

```
WITH t(name,total,date) AS ( VALUES
  ('a',100,'2016-01-01'::DATE),
  ('b',30,'2016-01-01'::DATE),
  ('c',40,'2016-01-01'::DATE),
  ('d',45,'2016-01-01'::DATE),
  ('a',20,'2016-01-02'::DATE),
  ('b',13,'2016-01-02'::DATE)
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (date)
  'a-b' AS diff,
  (nth_value(total,1) OVER (PARTITION BY date) -
  nth_value(total,2) OVER (PARTITION BY date)) total_diff,
  date
FROM t
WHERE name IN ('a','b');
```

Result:

```
 diff | total_diff |    date    
------+------------+------------
 a-b  |         70 | 2016-01-01
 a-b  |          7 | 2016-01-02
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer this is helpful, although I need to add that my data set is huge with values a,b repeating over different time periods. How will I calculate the difference only on the specific name value of the column.

Comment: please update the question with sample input and expected output, so the problem will be clear @ShwetaKamble

Comment: I am working on a problem, the data I cannot post here, so this is a sample data. I edited a little bit,let me know if you are able to understand my question.